# changing date input language without using 3rd parties component in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, datepicker, farsi

in my angular project , I faced a component where I have a date input.

the project language is Farsi(Persian) and I need to change the default date input language without

using 3rd party libraries. I know its sounds odd but I really cant add anything to the project due

to customers needs.

My Idea was ,  there is a relation between fonts and languages, I tried to change the font to "iransans" (which is a very common font for Farsi) but there was no difference.

Comment: can you provide the code sample or a small working example (StackBlitz)?

Comment: despite the application packages  , we decided to add ngbDatepicker for ease